# Custom Solr Fields in Sitecore 9 and Solr 7.2.1

Tags: solr, indexing, upgrade

I am converting my custom index fields from Sitecore 8.1.

Previously, I would declare them like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <myCustomIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
          <documentOptions>
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="parsed_content_keywords" returnType="customStringCol" storageType="yes" multiValued="true">
                MyProject.Search.ComputedFields.ParsedContentKeywords, MyProject.Search
              </field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
        </myCustomIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And **customStringCol** is declared like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <myCustomIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
              <typeMatch typeName="customStringCol"     type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_csm" multiValued="true" indexed="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
            </typeMatches>
          </fieldMap>
        </myCustomIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

In Sitecore 8.1 and Solr 4.10x, this configuration results in the index working correctly.
In Sitecore 9.1 and Solr 7.2.1, this results in the Solr log outputting the following SolrException:

```
ERROR: [doc=sitecore://web/{c6ccedd5-28a9-4707-8717-7482a48b538f}?lang=en&ver=1&ndx=sitecore_web_index] unknown field 'parsed_content_keywords_csm'
```

**Question**

How do I create a custom index in Sitecore 9.1 and Solr 7.2.1? Could someone share a sample config similar to the one I posted above that works in this scenario?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are creating an index as much as just adding fields. See Habitat for an example. https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Indexing/code/App_Config/Include/Foundation/Foundation.Indexing.config

Comment: have you populated the "Solr Managed Schema"? this gets me every time with errors like this

Comment: Chris Auer yes, this is what I'm trying to do - adding custom fields. And it looks like the way I'm configuring it is the same as in Habitat's example. Do I need to do anything else on the core configuration?

Comment: I changed the title - I'm indeed trying to create custom _fields_.

Answer (score 1):

### Fix `SolrException`

You could try using `stringCollection` type, which is already defined in Sitecore Solr-configuration:

```xml
<typeMatch type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" typeName="stringCollection" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
```

So, just change your field:

```xml
<field fieldName="parsed_content_keywords" returnType="stringCollection" storageType="YES">
    MyProject.Search.ComputedFields.ParsedContentKeywords, MyProject.Search
</field>
```

### To create custom index

#### 1. Create core in Solr:

You could use this script, but set custom values to `BASE_CORE_NAME` - already existing Solr core, which will be copied for a new one; `SOLR_ROOT` - path to solr.

```
echo off
SET BASE_CORE_NAME=[sitecore_web_index]
SET core_name=%1
SET SOLR_ROOT=c:\Program Files\solr-6.6.2
SET SOLR_INDEXES_DIR="%SOLR_ROOT%\server\solr\"

set NEW_INDEX_CONF_DIR=%SOLR_INDEXES_DIR%\%core_name%\conf
set BASE_INDEX_CONF_DIR=%SOLR_INDEXES_DIR%\%BASE_CORE_NAME%\conf
call mkdir %NEW_INDEX_CONF_DIR%
call xcopy %BASE_INDEX_CONF_DIR% %NEW_INDEX_CONF_DIR% /s

call "%SOLR_ROOT%\bin\solr" create -c %core_name%
```

And execute:

```
create-core.cmd [core_name]
```

#### 2. Create sitecore index

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <contentSearch>
            <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <indexes>
                    <index id="[YOUR_INDEX_NAME]"
                           type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                        <param desc="core">[SOLR_CORE_NAME]</param>
                        <param ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" desc="propertyStore"
                               param1="$(id)" />
                        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration" />
                        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
                           <!-- ADD YOUR CRAWLERS HERE -->
                        </locations>
                        <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
                        <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
                    </index>
                </indexes>
            </configuration>
        </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>

</configuration>
```

#### 3. Sitecore post-create steps

1. Populate "Solr Managed Schema"
2. Rebuild index